# Avoid full page reloads(!?) while navigation by updating only relevant sections in a set of webpages 

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a 3 column layout in my webpages and in my left most column, I have a list of pages which is consistent in all the pages.

Thus I was thinking if it would be preferable to prevent full page loading and update only the neccessary sections of the page when the user tries to switch to different page selecting fromt the left panel list.
Should I prevent the default behavior of links  using preventDefault() from jquery and update the address bar url & sections of page using ajax?

*I guess facebook also does the same thing when you try to switch between different group pages from the left panel on profile page !?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly reasonable optimization, yes—though the links should continue to work without JavaScript, for the benefit of crawlers and NoScripters and various other edge cases.

You can even make the effect seamless if you update the address bar with [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).  (The API is a bit new and [slightly glitchy across browsers](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API), but [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) promises to smooth out the differences.)  Browse the tree in [a project on github](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid) to see how this can work.

I believe github uses a jQuery plugin called [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) for their effect.  Maybe you can drop it in with minimal effort.

Comment: yes i would make full worthy links with `href` with `<a>` set to URLs but I would prevent full reload using prevent default. Thus the links should work in absence of JS, and suited for SEO as well

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false` to onclick handlers at links. These will prevent the links from being followed.

About updating the contents of the page: You should use Ajax indeed. Do you have any other specific questions?

Comment: actually i just wanted to know whether I should really do so.. which has been cleared by your answer. Do big websites like facebook etc also use these kind of mechanisms ?

Comment: I'm not a fan of Facebook. If you need an example, have a look at http://www.google.com. The Google search engine is an obvious example of an AJAX-driven website (including URL changes).